# Junit tests are failing but my methods seems fine in Java assignment

Tags: java, arraylist, junit, junit5

I'm working on an assignement that's due next week
So basically I have a class User with the following attributes

```java
private String userName, password;
private final Instant registrationDate;
private HashSet<User> setSubs;
private ArrayList<Post> listPosts;
private int Index;
```

The methods I'm trying to test are

```java
public Post addPost(String msg) {
    Post post = new Post(msg);
    listPosts.add(0, post);
    Index++;
    return post;
}
```

and

```java
public Post getPost(int i) {
    return listPosts.get(i);
}
```

Here's the class Post attributes

```java
private final String textPost; 
private final Instant dateCreation; //this.dateCreation = Instant.now();
private HashSet<User> likedUsers;
```

Here's the issue I'm facing, when testing the method addPost it gives the error `org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: expected: <true> but was: <false>`, when looking at the test's class I noticed that its failing in this bit

```java
    for (int i = 0; i < (self.getPostNb() - 1); i++) { //getPostNb() = listPost.size()
        assertTrue(self.getPost(i).isAfter(self.getPost(i + 1)));
    }
```

And for the method getPost it gives the error error `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: bound must be positive` whithout even running the test

Please any advice to fix them?
thanks

I need the Junit tests to all return successful, but only addPost and getPost are failing which made two other methods that uses them to also be aborted

Edit:
assertInvariant method

```
public void assertInvariant(User self) {
    // Put here the code to check the invariant:
    // @invariant getName() != null && !getName().isBlank();
    assertNotNull(self.getName());
    assertFalse(self.getName().isBlank());
    // @invariant getPassword() != null && !getPassword().isBlank();
    assertNotNull(self.getPassword());
    assertFalse(self.getPassword().isBlank());
    // @invariant getRegistrationDate() != null;
    assertNotNull(self.getRegistrationDate());
    // @invariant getSubscriptions() != null && !getSubscriptions().contains(null);
    assertNotNull(self.getSubscriptions());
    assertFalse(self.getSubscriptions().contains(null));
    // @invariant getSubscriptionNb() == getSubscriptions().size();
    assertEquals(self.getSubscriptionNb(), self.getSubscriptions().size());
    // @invariant getPosts() != null && !getPosts().contains(null);
    assertNotNull(self.getPosts());
    assertFalse(self.getPosts().contains(null));
    // @invariant (\forall int i, j; i >= 0 && i < j && j < getPostNb(); getPost(i).isAfter(getPost(j)));
    for (int i = 0; i < (self.getPostNb() - 1); i++) {
        assertTrue(self.getPost(i).isAfter(self.getPost(i + 1)));
    }
    // @invariant getPostNb() == getPosts().size();
    assertTrue(self.getPostNb() == self.getPosts().size());
    // @invariant previousIndex() >= -1 && previousIndex() < getPosts().size();
    assertTrue(self.previousIndex() >= -1);
    assertTrue(self.previousIndex() < self.getPosts().size());
    // @invariant nextIndex() >= 0 && nextIndex() <= getPosts().size();
    assertTrue(self.nextIndex() >= 0);
    assertTrue(self.nextIndex() <= self.getPosts().size());
    // @invariant nextIndex() == previousIndex() + 1;
    assertTrue(self.nextIndex() == self.previousIndex() + 1);
    // @invariant lastIndex() >= -1 && lastIndex() < getPosts().size();
    assertTrue(self.lastIndex() >= -1);
    assertTrue(self.lastIndex() < self.getPosts().size());
    // @invariant lastIndex() == previousIndex() || lastIndex() == nextIndex();
    assertTrue(self.lastIndex() == self.previousIndex() || self.lastIndex() == self.nextIndex());
}
```

Test method for addPost

```java
@ParameterizedTest
@MethodSource("userAndStringProvider")
public void testaddPost(User self, String msg) {
    assumeTrue(self != null);

    // Invariant:
    assertInvariant(self);

    // Pré-conditions:
    // @requires msg != null;
    assumeTrue(msg != null);

    // Oldies:
    Instant oldDate = Instant.now();
    // Wait until oldDate is really old:
    ArrayList<User> list = new ArrayList<User>(1);
    while (!oldDate.isBefore(Instant.now())) {
        list.add(self);
    }
    // old in:@ensures getPostNb() == \old(getPostNb()) + 1;
    int oldPostNb = self.getPostNb();
    // @ensures \old(lastIndex() >= 0) ==> nextIndex() == \old(nextIndex() + 1);
    int oldNextIndex = self.nextIndex();
    // @ensures \old(lastIndex() >= 0) ==> previousIndex() == \old(previousIndex() + 1);
    int oldPrevIndex = self.previousIndex();
    // @ensures \old(lastIndex() >= 0) ==> lastIndex() == \old(lastIndex() + 1);
    int oldLastIndex = self.lastIndex();

    // Exécution:
    Post result = self.addPost(msg);

    // Wait until exec date is really old:
    Instant execDate = Instant.now();
    while (!execDate.isBefore(Instant.now())) {
        list.add(null);
    }
    list = null;
    // Post-conditions:
    // @ensures getPost(0).equals(\result);
    assertEquals(self.getPost(0), result);
    // @ensures \result.getText().equals(msg);
    assertEquals(msg, result.getText());
    // @ensures getPostNb() == \old(getPostNb()) + 1;
    assertEquals(oldPostNb + 1, self.getPostNb());
    // @ensures oldDate.isBefore(\result.getDate());
    assertTrue(oldDate.isBefore(result.getDate()));
    // @ensures \result.getDate().isBefore(Instant.now());
    assertTrue(result.getDate().isBefore(Instant.now()));
    if (oldLastIndex >= 0) {
    // @ensures \old(lastIndex() >= 0) ==> nextIndex() == \old(nextIndex() + 1);
        assertEquals(oldNextIndex + 1, self.nextIndex());
        // @ensures \old(lastIndex() >= 0) ==> previousIndex() == \old(previousIndex() + 1);
        assertEquals(oldPrevIndex + 1, self.previousIndex());
        // @ensures \old(lastIndex() >= 0) ==> lastIndex() == \old(lastIndex() + 1);
        assertEquals(oldLastIndex + 1, self.lastIndex());
    } else {
        // @ensures \old(lastIndex() == -1) ==> nextIndex() == \old(nextIndex());
        assertEquals(oldNextIndex, self.nextIndex());
        // @ensures \old(lastIndex() == -1) ==> previousIndex() == \old(previousIndex());
        assertEquals(oldPrevIndex, self.previousIndex());
        // @ensures \old(lastIndex() == -1) ==> lastIndex() == \old(lastIndex());
        assertEquals(oldLastIndex, self.lastIndex());
    }

    // Invariant:
    assertInvariant(self);
}
```

Test method for getPost

```java
public void testgetPost(User self, int i) {
    assumeTrue(self != null);

    // Invariant:
    assertInvariant(self);

    // Pré-conditions:
    // @requires i >= 0 && i < getPostNb();
    assumeTrue(i >= 0 && i < self.getPostNb());

    // Save state for purity check:
    saveState(self);

    // Oldies:

    // Exécution:
    Post result = self.getPost(i);

    // Post-conditions:
    // @ensures \result.equals(getPosts().get(i));
    assertEquals(self.getPosts().get(i), result);

    // Assert purity:
    assertPurity(self);

    // Invariant:
    assertInvariant(self);
}
```

isAfter/isBefore method

```java
public boolean isAfter(Post p) {
    return getDate().isAfter(p.getDate()); //getDate().isBefore(p.getDate())
}
```

PS. I shouldn't be changing the test methods

UPDATE: the test data is provided by

```java
public static Stream<Arguments> userAndStringProvider() {
    return Stream
            .generate(() -> Arguments.of(userSupplier(), stringSupplier()))
            .limit(LG_STREAM);
}

public static List<User> allUser() {
    return Collections.unmodifiableList(allUsers);
}

public static User userSupplier() {
    return getRandomElt(allUsers);
}

public static <T> T getRandomElt(Collection<T> c) {
    int index = randInt(c.size());
    if (c instanceof List<?>) {
        return ((List<T>) c).get(index);
    }
    int i = 0;
    for (T elt : c) {
        if (i == index) {
            return elt;
        }
        i++;
    }
    throw new NoSuchElementException();
}
```

Comment: Can you please add the whole test method to your question? Is `self` of type `User` ?

Comment: And please add the implementation of `self.getPost(int).isAfter(...)`.

Comment: What do you expect `addPost` to return?

Comment: I've edited the post to add the requested method
self is of type User
addPost should return the newly added Post to the ArrayList

Comment: you are using `@ParameterizedTest` - what does the method `userAndStringProvider` do exactly?

Comment: here's the method asked
public static Stream<Arguments> userAndStringProvider() {
  return Stream.generate(() -> Arguments.of(userSupplier(), stringSupplier())).limit(LG_STREAM);
 }
public static List<User> allUser() {
  return Collections.unmodifiableList(allUsers);
 }
public static User userSupplier () {
  return getRandomElt(allUsers);
 }

Comment: I added the code to your question, and we're getting closer to the source of your `IllegalArgumentException`: the name of the `getRandomElt` method looks as if it has to do with "a call to a random generator" as @ThomasKläger wrote it in his answer. Can you please also add the sourcecode of the `getRandomElt` method to your question - and a statement if it's possible to change the test data provider and any of the methods it uses.

Comment: heres the code of getRandomElt

public static <T> T getRandomElt(Collection<T> c) {
  int index = randInt(c.size());
  if (c instanceof List<?>) {
   return ((List<T>) c).get(index);
  }
  int i = 0;
  for (T elt : c) {
   if (i == index) {
    return elt;
   }
   i++;
  }
  throw new NoSuchElementException();
 }

Comment: now, the code for the method `int randInt(int)` is missing - but probably it calls `java.util.Random.nextInt(int)` somewhere. Can you confirm this or provide the code? And please: edit your question to add it directly there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so recently I was in a meeting with my professor, and showed him this error and here's the answer
Apparently I'm supposed to have 3 indexes instead of one, and that's what have been messing with th tests causing them to fails
Alas, when I did the changes, the tests were successful

```
    public Post addPost(String msg) {
        Post post = new Post(msg);
        listPosts.add(0, post);
        previousIndex++; //index of the previous post
        nextIndex++;     //index of the next post
        lastIndex++;     //index of the last post visited (or current post)
        return post;
    }
```

And for getPost, it was correct this whole time
I want to thank everyone that participated in helping me solve this issues, and I wish you all a good rest of day
Thanks and Goodbye

Answer (score 0):

You add new posts to the end of the `listPosts`:

```
    public Post addPost(String msg) {
        listPosts.add(new Post(msg));
        Index++;
        return new Post(msg);
    }
```

That means that the posts are ordered in ascending `dateCreation` order (i.e. `listPosts.get(0)` is created first, then `listPosts.get(1)`, then later posts) and that also means that

```
    self.getPost(i).isAfter(self.getPost(i + 1))
```

can never be true. You either have to change that condition to

```
    self.getPost(i).isBefore(self.getPost(i + 1))
```

or add new posts to the front of the list:

```
    public Post addPost(String msg) {
        listPosts.add(0, new Post(msg));
        Index++;
        return new Post(msg);
    }
```

---

Also note that `addPost()` creates two distinct `Post` objects which probably is not what you want. You probably want

```
    public Post addPost(String msg) {
        Post post = new Post(msg);
        listPosts.add(0, post);
        Index++;
        return post;
    }
```

---

For the `IllegalArgumentException` with the message "bound must be positive":

A search over the JDK17 source code result in a single possible cause for that message: a call to a random generator with an upper bound that is less than zero.

Since your code doesn't contain any usage of a random generator it is impossible to say what the problem is.

Maybe when you include the stacktrace of that exception that could help to pin down the problem.

Comment: thanks for your respond
addPost() is still giving the same error even after the changes, and the test method cannot be changed
now getPost() is giving the same error as addPost(), any idea how to fix it?

Comment: @Absentia is it still failing on the line `assertTrue(self.getPost(i).isAfter(self.getPost(i + 1)));`? Is it failing some other assertion? `assertInvariant()` has 10 `assertTrue()` calls that will all fail with exactly the same message which doesn't really help diagnosing the problem. Maybe now it is one of the tests concerning the `previousIndex` / `lastIndex` and similar?

Comment: Note that besides `assertTrue(condition)` there is a variant [`assertTrue(condition, message)`](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/5.0.1/api/org/junit/jupiter/api/Assertions.html#assertTrue-boolean-java.lang.String-) which would help in finding the failing condition.

Comment: yes it's still failing in assertTrue(self.getPost(i).isAfter(self.getPost(i + 1))), if i comment it the error now shows up in  assertTrue(self.nextIndex() == self.previousIndex() + 1);
here are their respective methods 
public int nextIndex() {
   if (hasNext()) {
            return this.Index ++;
        }
        return this.getPosts().size();
 }
public int previousIndex() {
  if (hasPrevious()) {
            return this.Index--;
        }
        return -1;
 }